# is the function of fflush(stdin) similar to that of scanf("%*[^\n]%*c")?

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

I just found the below code. but I don't understand what this means `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c")`. What does  `^\n` mean? What does the `*` before `^\n` and `c` mean?

I want to make a loop in C that, when the program asks for an integer and the user types a non-digit character, the program asks again for an integer.

> ```
>     /*
>
>          This program calculates the mean score of a user 4 individual 
>          scores,and outputs the mean and a final grade
>          Input: score1, score2,score2, score3
>          Output: Mean, FinalGrade
>
>         */
>
>             #include <stdio.h>
>         //#include <stdlib.h>
>
>         int main(void){
>           int userScore = 0; //Stores the scores that the user inputs
>           float meanValue = 0.0f; //Stores the user mean of all the notes
>           char testChar = 'f'; //Used to avoid that the code crashes
>           char grade = 'E'; //Stores the final 
>           int i = 0; //Auxiliar used in the for statement
>
>           printf("\nWelcome to the program \n Tell me if Im clever enough! \n Designed for humans \n\n\n");
>           printf("Enter your 4 notes between 0 and 100 to calculate your course grade\n\n");
>
>           // Asks the 4 notes. 
>           for ( ; i<=3 ; i++ ){
>             printf("Please, enter your score number %d: ", i+1);
>
>             //If the note is not valid, ask for it again
>
>             //This is tests if the user input is a valid integer.
>             if ( ( scanf("%d%c", &userScore, &testChar)!=2 ||testChar!='\n'))
> {
>               i-=1;
>               scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
>
>             }else{ //Enter here if the user input is an integer
>               if ( userScore>=0 && userScore<=100 ){
>             //Add the value to the mean
>             meanValue += userScore;
>               }else{ //Enter here if the user input a non valid integer
>             i-=1;
>             //scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
>               }    
>             }
>           }
>
>           //Calculates the mean value of the 4 scores
>           meanValue = meanValue/4;
>
>           // Select your final grade according to the final mean
>           if (meanValue>= 90 && meanValue <=100){
>             grade = 'A';
>           } else if(meanValue>= 80 && meanValue <90){
>             grade = 'B';
>           } else if (meanValue>= 70 && meanValue <80){
>             grade = 'C';
>           } else if(meanValue>= 60 && meanValue <70){
>             grade = 'D';
>           }
>           printf("Your final score is: %2.2f --> %c \n\n" , meanValue, grade);
>
>           return 0;
>         }
> ```

Comment: Use only `fgets()` for user input.

Comment: `fflush()` on an input stream is undefined, so... No.

Comment: Totally no. Even posix does not define what flushing input actually does on terminals

Comment: if scanf("%*[^\n]%*c") is used to clear stdin cant we just use fflush(stdin)